# Artifactory 7.12.6: "Download snippet" button in setMeUp returns jsonMappingException

Tags: artifactory

After upgrading frog-artifactory-oss from 7.10.5 to 7.12.6 the "Download snippet" button in the setMeUp dialog results in 400 html code response from the artifactory server. When inspecting the consol.log on the server the following stack trace appears:

```
2021-02-02T13:34:53.300Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [5427901e9c0247cd] [.JsonMappingExceptionMapper:45] [http-nio-8081-exec-6] - Error parsing json body
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of org.artifactory.ui.rest.model.setmeup.MavenSettingModel out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1712801b; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:875)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
    at org.artifactory.rest.common.util.JsonUtil.mapDataToModel(JsonUtil.java:126)
    at org.artifactory.ui.rest.resource.artifacts.setmeup.SetMeUpResource.downloadMavenSnippet(SetMeUpResource.java:145)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:201)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:530)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.authenticateAndExecute(AccessFilter.java:394)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:258)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryTracingFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryTracingFilter.java:32)
```

Has anybody experienced this as well or got any ideas about the reason for this?

Comment: Ok, it seems this is a known problem on versions 7.11.2, 7.11.5, 7.12.5 and 7.12.6 according to frog jira issue RTFACT-24792. "Downloading the generated configuration snippet for Gradle, Ivy and Maven repositories in not working"

Comment: You should post this as an answer. Also link the Jira issue in the answer. I, for one, would definitely upvote it.